# if variable equals any number in list

Tags: python, if-statement

I have recently been working on a test mark calculator, and I was hoping to do something like this:

```
if percent = anything in lv1:
 print("This is a Level 1 mark.")
```

Is there any way I could accomplish this within Python's syntax?

Comment: There is an `any` method, but it's not clear what you have in your list

Comment: Unlike C, assignment in Python does not return value,.

Answer (score 3):

To check if element in list just

```
if percent in lv1:
    print("This is a Level 1 mark.")
```

BTW: `=` in Python is assignment operator, not equality check.

Answer (score 1):

```
if percent in lv1:
    print("something")
```